# missing doxygen special command \alias

Tags: request, doxygen

this is my first post…
I create a large documentation using *doxygen* and I would like to
request a feature to create an **ALIAS** into the documentation. The
**ALIAS** definition itself should be invisible like an *\anchor* etc…

=> this feature would dramatically reduce the complexity of *doxygen* documentation

**example (pseudo-doxygen:-)**

```
/// \defgroup MQ_Slave_C_API MQ_Slave_C_API                                                                            
/// \ingroup  MQ_C_API                                                                                                 
/// \{
/// \alias  myalias{1}=XXXX\1YYYY                                                                                                             
…some code…
/// \brief \myalias{hello}
…some code…
/// \}
```

thanks.

Comment: Please always specify the used version of doxygen. ALIASES have to be specified in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile), looks like you already saw that syntax.

Comment: > doxygen -v
1.8.11

this is a feature request. I already know that i can define ALIASES in a doxygen-file… this request is to define an ALIAS in the source-code-file(s) also.